# C++ ERROR: Control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c++

Hi I am working on some C++ code in Xcode and I get this error `Control may reach end of non-void function`. I am also using the Unreal engine standard for code so that is where the `FText` and `int32` comes from. Here is my code:

```
do {
// get a guess from the player
    int32 CurrentTry = BCGame.GetCurrentTry();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Try " << CurrentTry << ". Enter your guess: ";
    FText Guess = "";
    std::getline(std::cin,Guess);

    Status = BCGame.CheckGuessValidity(Guess);
    switch (Status)
    {
    case EGuessStatus::Wrong_Length:
        std::cout << "Please enter a " << BCGame.GetHiddenWordLength() << " letter word.\n";
        break;

    case EGuessStatus::Not_Isogram:
        std::cout << "Please enter a word without repeating letters.\n";
        break;

    case EGuessStatus::Not_Lowercase:
        std::cout << "Please enter all lowercase letters.\n";
        break;

    default:
        return  Guess;
    }
} while (Status != EGuessStatus::OK);
}
```

Please someone help.

Comment: The error should be pretty self-explaining. You're missing a `return` statement in your function somewhere. For example what will be returned if the loop ends?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but what is `FText`? Is it just an alias for `std::string`? Why have such an alias? It makes the code harder to read and understand. Also please try to avoid other non-standard types like `int32`. If you need an explicit signed 32-bit integer then use the standard `int32_t` from [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint). If you *don't* need a specific sized integer (which you probably don't) then just use plain `int`.

Comment: And because of what Joachim has mentioned, the code you showed is not enough to help you since we need to see the whole function.

Comment: FText is an Unreal Type. It's pretty much as you said, string.

Comment: They are all correct with above assessments. We need to see your function/method signature, only assuming it's an FText return type, in which case all paths don't return value. You are not solving for all cases, even though you're breaking the loop, you need to ensure it returns something eventually. IF all assumptions above are correct, put a return statement at the closing inners of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You are not showing your complete function, but obviously it is declared to return something; and the `default` path in the switch also does return `Guess`.

However, the other three paths in the switch do not return anything, the flow goes behind the switch and there is nothing more. So you have a function that returns nothing, but it *needs* to return something - just as the message said.